# Error: A non-null value must be returned since the return type 'int' doesn't allow null. int sum() { ^ Error: Compilation failed

Tags: dart

estoy ejercitando con `dart` y resulta que cuando declaro una variable y le almaceno un objeto de tipo array de enteros para luego aplicar al objeto el metodo `reduce` este me retorna el siguiente error:

> Error: A non-null value must be returned since the return type 'int' doesn't allow null.
> int sum() {
> ^
> Error: Compilation failed.

Mi funcion deberia retornar un entero.

```
int sum() {
List<int> numbers = [1, 5, 8, 10];
numbers.reduce((a, b) => {
  return a + b;
});
}


void main() {
print(sum());
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`[SOLUCIONADO]`

Lo que me paso es que si bien el metodo me retorna un objeto de tipo entero, este debia ser almacenado en una variable

`int result`

Para luego esta sea retornada

```
int result = numbers.reduce((a, b) => a + b);
return result;
```